# How to set Selection Limit of Multiselect Dropdown with ng-repeat value

Tags: angularjs, dropdown, multi-select

I am using [AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main) in my app, In the examples it said I can set the `selectionLimit` inside the `extra-settings` in the angular controller but the `selectionLimit` that I want the dropdown to have is dynamic (It's a `ng-repeat` value which the user can change anytime in the `input` box)

The dropdown is generated by `ng-repeat`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in mainCtrl.lineDetails">
    <td>
        <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="true" options="mainCtrl.Customers" selected-model="detail.SelectedCustomers" extra-settings="mainCtrl.selectedCustomersSettings">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number" id="SelectionLimit" name="SelectionLimit" ng-model="detail.SelectionLimit" ng-min="0" required/>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**settings**

```
self.selectedCustomersSettings = {
    searchField: 'name',
    enableSearch: true,
    displayProp: 'name',
    scrollableHeight: '300px',
    scrollable: true,
    keyboardControls: true,
    idProperty: 'name',
    buttonClasses: 'form-control drpdwn-btn'
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution below worked for me. I added the settings `inline` so that I can set the `selectionLimit` with the `ng-repeat` value.

```
<div ng-dropdown-multiselect="true" options="mainCtrl.Customers" selected-model="detail.SelectedCustomers" extra-settings="{searchField: 'name',enableSearch: true,displayProp: 'name',scrollableHeight: '300px',scrollable: true,keyboardControls: true,idProperty: 'name',buttonClasses: 'form-control drpdwn-btn',selectionLimit:detail.NoOfStores}" >
</div>
```